# ArcGIS Server and PostgreSQL Geoprocessing Service gives ERROR 001270

Tags: postgresql, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service, error-001270

I'm hitting an error when publishing a model from ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 to ArcGIS Server 10.1.  The model I want to publish uses a layer from a Postgres DB defined via a Query Layer in my MXD.  The model is very simple for now, run the Select function on the Query Layer and return the result as a shapefile.

Publishing fails with a message of:

> Failed to create service definition

and

> ERROR 001270: Consolidating the data failed

in the results window.

This error links to http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00vp0000002r001270

I have taken all of the steps mentioned therein - shortening service names, paths etc, and ensuring that the DB connection is registered in my ArcGIS Server instance.  I can add the PG layer as a standalone map service which works fine.

My PostgreSQL instance (9.1.3) is not configured as an Esri Enterprise Geodatabase, so that could be an issue. PostGIS 1.5.3 is installed on the DB, which is currently used for web mapping (MapServer) and hopefully data connections into Esri geoprocessing services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some progress here.  Instead of using an existing Postgres DB, I created a totally new Postgres instance on my ArcGIS Server and used the instructions found [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Creating_a_database_and_geodatabase_in_PostgreSQL/002p000000ss000000/) to create an Enterprise GDB. This works and I can then publish models with PG layers in them!

Next step is the use the documentation [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Enabling_geodatabase_functionality_in_an_existing_PostgreSQL_database/002p000000sv000000/) on my existing Postgres DB.